# JQuery Parallax effect. OnScroll event very Laggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, parallax, effect

I'm trying to make a simple Parallax effect in js.

There is my code:

```
function parallax(){
    $(".parallax").css("backgroundPosition","50% "+$(document).scrollTop()+"px");
}
parallax();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    parallax();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/makitos666/whb6Ldup/3/

It is fully functional, but I have a performance issue. When I make scroll with the mouse wheel, there make 100px steps, and all works well. But when I use a touchable input, like touchpad or smartphone there is much more precision, and the scroll event is triggered a lot of times. In my laptop all works well, but if you use a slow computer or Android mobile the effect is very laggy.

Do you know if this is possible? Or do I need to change everything?

Or if you know some responsive and mobile friendly library foor this effect, I'm interested too.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, after various hours investigating by myself, this is my conclusion:

The JS OnScroll event is not the best way to make a resposive Parallax effect, this only will work with a dedicated graphic card, and this is not resposive (for me).

The solution is this: https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw (by keithclark)

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}

#slide2 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/3/");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

A pure CSS Parallax effect. Is the same as mine, but much more effective. If you know another solution for that, I want to know it! ;)

**UPDATE**

Well, this solution works, but seems that the backbround-attachment: fixed dont works well in Android Phones.
Still searching a solution.